# How to assign the OnClose event of an MDIChild at runtime?

Tags: delphi, event-handling, delphi-7

This is the code in main Form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm : array [1..5] of TForm;
  i : Integer;
begin
  For i:= 1 to 5 do begin
    AForm[i]:= TForm.Create(nil);
    With AForm[i] do begin
      Parent := Self;
      BorderStyle:= bsSizeToolWin;
      OnClose <<< Here i would like change Action to caFree
      FormStyle:=fsMDIChild;
      Show;
      Caption:=IntToStr(i);
    end;
    if i mod 2 = 0 Then AForm[i].Color:=clRed else AForm[i].Color:=clBlue;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to assign the OnClose event of the child Form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an event handler, and assign it to the OnClose event of the form.

Since you are not, yet, creating a new class for your MDI child form, you would most likely put the event handler in the main form.

```
procedure TForm1.ChildFormClose(Sender: TObject; 
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Assign it like this:

```
OnClose := ChildFormClose;
```

In due course I expect you'll derive classes for your MDI children. You could move the event to these new classes, or a common base. That said, I would probably not do so. It's a method that fits well inside the main form.

Some asides. I don't believe that you should specify Parent for an MDI child. As I recall, the framework locates the single MDI window automatically. I think your setting of Parent is ignored, has no effect, and so should be removed. Im also curious about the setting of the MDI children's border style. Does that have any effect?

Comment: Thank you David, this solved my problem.
About the border style, really have no effect.